# jquery jstree cookies plugin throwing undefined error

Tags: jquery, cookies, jstree

I need to user jquery jstree cookies plugin. My script is as follows:

This is the script to use cookies plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


     $("#tree").jstree({  



         "xml_data" : {  

             "ajax" : {  

                 "url" : "jstree.xml" 

             },  

             "xsl" : "nest"


         },  
         "themes" : {  

             "theme" : "classic",  

            "dots" : true,  

             "icons" : true 

         },  
         "ui": {
         "save_selected" : false,
         },

        "search" : {  

                 "case_insensitive" : true,  

                 "ajax" : {  

                     "url" : "jstree.xml" 

                 }  

             }, 

        "cookies" : { 
                    "cookie_options" : {
                                    "path": "C:/Users/docs"

                                    } 
                }, 


              "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types", "search"] 


    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {

        $("#tree").jstree("toggle_node", data.rslt.obj);
```

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 25 Feb 2013 19:46:57 UTC


Message: Exception thrown and not caught
Line: 2053
Char: 42
Code: 0
jquery.jstree.js
```

this is the line it is complaining:

```
if(typeof $.cookie === "undefined") { throw "jsTree cookie: jQuery cookie plugin not included."; }
```

is cookies plugin part of jstree.js file or there is a separate js for cookies plugin? If there is a different cookies.js file, where can I get this file? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsTree plugin requires the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to use cookies. Be sure to load it before loading jsTree.

---

Example code that works:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/jstree/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
  <script>
$(function() {
   $("#tree").jstree({  
     "cookies" : { 
                    "cookie_options" : {
                                    path: 'c:/Users/hceylan1/docs'
                                    } 
                },
                "xml_data" : {
            "data" : "" +
"<root>" +
    "<item id='node_1'>" +
        "<content><name>Root node 1</name></content>" +
    "</item>" +
    "<item>" +
        "<content><name>Root node 2</name></content>" +
    "</item>" +
    "<item parent_id='node_1'>" +
        "<content><name>Child node</name></content>" +
    "</item>" +
"</root>"
        },

    "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types", "search", "cookies"] 
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {

        $("#tree").jstree("toggle_node", data.rslt.obj);
    });
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tree">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I downlaoded jcookie.js version 1.2.0 from http://plugins.jquery.com/jcookie/, I am still having the same issue. I am loading it before jstree plugin, any ideas?

Comment: First of all I fixed the link for the cookie plugin you should be using. Second of all, show me your code.

Comment: I use jquery version: 1.7.2, jstree version: jsTree 1.0-rc3 and just downloaded jcookie version : 1.2.0. I am still getting the eroor ***correction. My use case is this. when I click on a node, I need to open up a new browser and load some images related to that node id. Basically I need to carry over the node_id of a node to a new browser session. This is doable right?

Comment: I also updated my original post to show the script for jstree using cookies plugin.

Comment: Yes. You may need to read up on the details of how to do it in the jsTree documentation but your error should be resolved, at least.

Comment: I am really sorry, I was not getting error because I did not include cookies plugin in the script. After I include, I still get the error: line 2052 on jstree.js: if(typeof $.cookie === "undefined") { throw "jsTree cookie: jQuery cookie plugin not included."; }

Comment: See the pastebin link I provided. That functions correctly. See how your code differs, how that code works and then adjust your code as needed.

Comment: I cannot access that link from work. It is blocked. Can you copy and paste it here, please.

Comment: It's a bit long to paste here. I will add it to the bottom of my answer. Don't forget you can upvote my answer if it has helped you.